# Image track animation is jittery on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried adding passive listeners and all of that, thinking they would change anything, but whenever I'm scrolling through this on mobile, it interrupts the sliding animation and goes to where my finger is. On the desktop, this doesn't happen. I want to make this look smooth on all devices.

Sorry if it's hard to view - I know most people on StackOverflow view on Desktop.

```js
const track = document.getElementById("image-track");

const handleOnDown = e => {
  track.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.clientX;
};

const handleOnUp = () => {
  track.dataset.mouseDownAt = "0";
  track.dataset.prevPercentage = track.dataset.percentage;
};

const handleOnMove = e => {
  if (track.dataset.mouseDownAt === "0") return;

  const mouseDelta = parseFloat(track.dataset.mouseDownAt) - e.clientX;
  const maxDelta = track.offsetWidth;

  const percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100;
  const nextPercentageUnconstrained = parseFloat(track.dataset.prevPercentage) + percentage;

  track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentageUnconstrained;

  track.animate(
    {
      transform: `translate(${nextPercentageUnconstrained}%, -50%)` 
    },
    { duration: 1000, fill: "forwards", passive: true}
  );

  for (const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")) {
    image.animate(
      {
        objectPosition: `${100 + nextPercentageUnconstrained}% center` 
      },
      { duration: 1000, fill: "forwards", passive: true }
    );
  }
};

/* -- Add event listeners to the div element -- */
track.addEventListener("mousedown", handleOnDown);
track.addEventListener("touchstart", e => handleOnDown(e.touches[0]), { passive: true });
track.addEventListener("mouseup", handleOnUp);
track.addEventListener("touchend", e => handleOnUp(e.touches[0]), { passive: true });
track.addEventListener("mousemove", handleOnMove);
track.addEventListener("touchmove", e => handleOnMove(e.touches[0]), { passive: true });
```

```css
[aria-label="Famous People at Leopolds"] {
    height: 103vmin;
    width: 99.5%;
    background: radial-gradient(rgb(230, 230, 180), rgb(235, 235, 141));
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #bfb398;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -2vh;
}

[aria-label="Famous People at Leopolds"] h2 {
    margin: 17px;
    font-size: 10vmin;
    color: #9D000D;
}

.imageContainer {
    position: relative;
}

.imageContainer h3 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 95%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
    width: 50vw;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Ageo';
}

#image-track {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4vmin;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 10%;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    user-select: none;
}

#image-track .image {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 48vmin;
    height: 65vmin;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 100% center;
}
```

```html
        <section aria-label="Famous People at Leopolds">
            <h2>Famously Good!</h2>
            <div id="image-track" data-mouse-down-at="0" data-prev-percentage="0">
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Miley-Cyrus-Leopolds.webp" title="Miley-Cyrus with Ice Cream" alt="Miley-Cyrus with Ice Cream in hand" 
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3>Miley Cyrus</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Tom-Cruise-Leopolds.webp" title="Tom Cruise and Stratton"  alt="Tom Cruise and Stratton Leopold sharing ice cream" 
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3>Tom Cruise</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/William-Macy-Leopolds.webp" title="William Macy and Stratton"  alt="William Macy and Stratton Leopold pictured in the shop" 
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3>William Macy</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Paula-Deen-Leopolds.webp" title="Paula Deen and Stratton"  alt="Paula Deen and Stratton Leopold locked in a side embrace, looking into the camera with ice cream in frame" 
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3>Paula Deen</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Mini-Anden-Niki-Taylor-Leopolds.webp" title="Mini Anden and Niki Taylor"  alt="Mini Anden and Niki Taylor pictured in front of the store window licking ice cream"
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3 style="top:89%">Mini Anden & Niki Taylor</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Alan-Rickman-Leopolds.webp" title="Alan Rickman in Leopolds"  alt="Alan Rickman pictured finishing ice cream in the shop"
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3>Alan Rickman</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Kimberly-Schlapman-Leopolds.webp" title="Kimberly Schlapman in Leopolds"  alt="Kimberly Schlapman and Stratton Leopold locked in a side embrace in the shop"
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3 style="min-width: 300px;">Kimberly Schlapman</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Patti-LuPone-Leopolds.webp" title="Patti Lupone outside Leopolds" alt="Patti LuPone and Stratton Leopold locked in a side embrace outside the shop"
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3>Patti LuPone</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="imageContainer">
                    <img class="image" src="Images/Philip-Hoffman-Leopolds.webp" title="Phillip Hoffman" alt="Phillip Hoffman enjoying Leopolds Ice Cream"
                    loading="lazy" decoding="async"  width="244" height="244" draggable="false" />
                    <h3>Philip Hoffman</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```